# Scrapy: How to call a function within sitemap_rules?

Tags: scrapy

I am using the sitemap crawler of scrapy 2.1.0 and want to exclude certain urls.

Therefore I use:

```
sitemap_rules=[
    ('.*-ID-\d*$', 'parse_shop'),
]
```

This will parse every URL containing an ID within the string.

Now certain IDs are invalid, which I do know if I can call a method. This function returns false in case the ID is invalid. In this case I do not want to crawl this particular URL.

```
def id_valid(ID):
    return True # in case true
```

How could I call this from sitemap rules and exclude all URLs with invalid ID?

Comment: You could use [?!](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-21) in the regular expression. Otherwise, I don’t think there’s a clean solution: either you reimplement a private method of the sitemap spider (which may break your spider in the future), or you copy the whole implementation of the sitemap spider and fork it (you’ll not get future improvements to the spider, but future changes will not break it either).

Comment: Not sure if I explained it well since I found "start_requests" that might lead in the right direction but could not get it to work so far:     def start_requests(self):
        return yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'par1':'val1'})

Comment: Better update the question with your `start_requests` code, then. `return yield` in the same line looks wrong, though, you should be using either one or the other.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up the questions. My comment was ment for another one. So I understand your comment that it is not practially possible to call the function but implement a regex instead? That might be a tough gegex as I want to validate a code-39 number.

Comment: Oh, there seems to be already a method for this: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.SitemapSpider.sitemap_filter

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.